# get posts of taxonomy parent?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new with custom post type - taxonomy wordpress.
I created a template page to show list of products in custome taxonomy but i dont know how exactly to do.
Example:
Category
 SubCategory
Product A in Category and B in Category>SubCategory.I want to click Category will show only Product A and if i click SubCat will show only Product B.
Tks for helping!

```
                <?php
                $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
                $args = array(
                  'post_type' => array('san-pham'),
                  'post_status' => 'publish', 
                  'order' => 'DESC', 
                  'orderby' => 'date', 
                  'posts_per_page' => 100, 
                  'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                );

                $eq_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
                $offset = 0;
                $count = 0;
                $eq_total_posts = $eq_query->found_posts - $offset;
                if ($eq_query->have_posts()) : // The Loop
                $eq_count = $args['paged'] * $args['posts_per_page'] - $args['posts_per_page']; // Count items
                ?>
                <?php 
                while ($eq_query->have_posts()): $eq_query->the_post();
                $eq_count++;
                $count++;
                ?>
                <?php
                      if ($count == 4) {
                              $p4 = 'four';
                              $count = 0;
                      } else { $p4 = ''; }
                ?>
                <div <?php post_class($p4); ?> id="pro-cat">
                  ....
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> 
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may helps you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179858/get-direct-children-of-custom-taxonomy

Comment: Pump , i didnt get it .